# jRuby / Rails sort hash by another hash value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, jruby

I have a hash that will render my html differently based on a particular variable. The variable is within the hash. So I am wondering how I can pass a hash value to a group by. to sort the rest heres what I am trying, maybe this will explain it better than me wording it.

```
<% grouped = svcs.group_by { |svc| svc[val[:sorttype]] } %>
```

val is a multidimensional hash. the first 2 key value pairs sorttype and one other are simple key and value, the 3rd piece (svcs) contains the equivilent of a 2D hash. Which if I manually type the type of sort I want to apply to it for the group by it works ie:

```
<% grouped = svcs.group_by { |svc| svc[:service_name] } %>
```

in PHP i know in a similar instance I can pass a variable of some sort to something like this and have it work. I assume such is the case here. However Im not sure how to put the variable in. Cause all the ways Ive tried don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a little.

Rails' has a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` that will not distinguish between string and symbol keys; if you're using one of those, it should work as-is.

If it's not, it depends what the `val` entries are--if they're strings, convert to a symbol using `to_sym`, e.g., `svc[val[:sorttype].to_sym]`.

Comment: thats exactly what i needed. That to_sym bit. Appending that solved it . Thank you yet again. :-D

Comment: @chris No problem; that trips people up sometimes.